# Turn off SSL certificate verification in karate

Tags: java, ssl, postman, karate

I am using Karate framework. As the server requires to do so, I am trying to connect to it with `mutual auth` as described here:
https://github.com/intuit/karate#x509-certificate-authentication

```
* configure ssl = { trustStore : 'classpath:certstore.pfx', trustStorePassword: 'certpassword', trustStoreType: 'pkcs12' };
```

I am getting this error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
```

Does anyone knows how to skip the `SSL certificate verification` like I do in Postman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have used `keystore` instead of `trustStore`.

```
* configure ssl = { keyStore : 'classpath:certstore.pfx', keyStorePassword: 'certpassword', keyStoreType: 'pkcs12' };
```

Answer (score 1):

This should use HTTPS but ignore the certificate:

```
* configure ssl = true
```

Docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#configure

Comment: I solved it. I was using `trustStore` instead of `keyStore`. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Peter, unfortunately mutual auth is not possible with your answer.

Comment: @lembas then please add an answer yourself. your question is confusing as it says skip.